# How to disable plain_text.wrap_long_lines option in geckodriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, geckodriver

Using selenium-webdriver and capybara in rspec, in a features spec I'm trying to get the HTTP response of a plain text request, namely /robots.txt

But instead of getting the plain text response, I get the text response wrapped in HTML:

```
   expected: "User-agent: *\nDisallow:\n\nSitemap: https://prj.org/sitemap.xml\n"
        got: "<html><head><link rel=\"alternate stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"resource://content-accessible/plaintext.css\" title=\"Wrap Long Lines\"></head><body><pre>User-agent: *\nDisallow:\n\nSitemap: https://prj.org/sitemap.xml\n</pre></body></html>"
```

When fetching /robots.txt with curl I get the expected plain text response. So I've been through Firefox options, and I found out I needed to disable *plain_text.wrap_long_lines* option.

And I cannot succeed to pass the option to geckodriver.

I first tried to pass it to the `Options` object, like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  options.headless!
  options.add_preference 'plain_text.wrap_long_lines', false

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :firefox, options: options
end
```

Then I tried to pass it to a `Profile` object.

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  options.headless!

  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['plain_text.wrap_long_lines'] = false

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :firefox, options: options, profile: profile
end
```

In both cases, the result is the same. Any idea as per why? Thanks!

Using:

- selenium-webdriver 3.14.1
- capybara 3.7.2
- geckodriver 0.22.0

Comment: Show the code for the test - this has nothing to do with a Firefox option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing here is that when Firefox opens a text file it automatically wraps it in some boilerplate html in order for the browser to be able to display it.  You don't show your test code you're using - but whatever you're doing should boil down to something like

```
# If using minitest
visit('/robots.txt')
find('body > pre').assert_text("User-agent: *\nDisallow:\n\nSitemap: https://prj.org/sitemap.xml\n", exact: true)

# If using RSpec
visit('/robots.txt')
expect(find('body > pr')).to have_text("User-agent: *\nDisallow:\n\nSitemap: https://prj.org/sitemap.xml\n", exact: true)
```